# Como inserir dados em duas tabelas relacionadas entre si por chave estrangeira ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sql-insert

Queria uma ajuda com esse problema. Estou tentando inserir dados no banco usando duas tabelas relacionadas com foreign key, mas não consigo fazer quando tem mais de duas tabelas. Até consegui fazer com duas, mas colocando uma terceira, não estou conseguindo. Vou mostrar os códigos:

***FORM***

```
<?php include "pagina-ini.php"; ?>

<form class="form-signin" id="fale_conosco" name="fale_conosco" action="form_grupo_estudo_proc.php" method="post">
<h3>Formulário de inscrição para os Grupos de Estudo</h3>

<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">

  Grupo de Estudo:
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
  <select class="form-control text-uppercase npi" name="nome_grupo" id="nome_grupo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="grupo1">Aspectos atuais do Direito do Consumidor</option>
            <option value="grupo2">Bioética e Biodireito IV</option>
            <option value="grupo4">Direito Civil e proteção dos vulneráveis</option>
            <option value="grupo5">Minorias e Grupos Vulneráveis</option>
            <option value="grupo6">Processo penal contemporâneo</option>
            <option value="grupo7">Projeto Diálogos Fundamentais</option>
            <option value="grupo8">Raízes da desigualdade à luz da literatura</option>

            

        </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

  Nome:
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <input class="form-control text-uppercase npi" type="text" id="txt_nome" name="nome" maxLength="48" required>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">

  E-mail:
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <input class="form-control text-lowercase npi" type="text" id="txt_email" name="email" maxLength="48" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">

 Celular:
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <input class="form-control text-lowercase npi" type="text" id="celular" name="celular" maxLength="11"  pattern="^\([1-9]{2}\) (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$" required>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">

 Período Letivo:
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
  <select class="form-control text-uppercase npi" name="periodo_letivo" id="periodo_letivo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="periodo1">2021/1</option>
            <option value="periodo2">2021/2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

 Matrícula:
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <input class="form-control text-lowercase npi" type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula" maxLength="5"  pattern="^\[0-9]\" required>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">

 Situação:
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
  <select class="form-control text-uppercase npi" name="situacao" id="situacao">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="ativo">Ativo</option>
            <option value="inativo">Inativo</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">

 <br>
<img src="lib/captcha.php?l=150&a=50&tf=20&ql=5">
<br>

<!--
  Digite os caracteres da imagem
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <input class="form-control npi" type="text" id="txt_captcha" name="txt_captcha" maxLength="5" required>
 </div>
</div>
-->

<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="but_enviar" name="but_enviar" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php include "pagina-ter.php"; ?>

<?php
/*
include "lib/html.php";

page_begin("fale_conosco", "fale_conosco_proc.php");
p_begin("");

div_begin("", "align=center");
img("img/logo_fale_conosco.jpg", "border=0");
br();
label("FALE CONOSCO", true);
div_end();
br();
label("Telefone: 31 3769-1919", false);
br();
br();
label("Ramais:", false);
br();
label("1. Diretoria", false);
br();
label("2. Secretaria", false);
br();
label("3. Financeiro", false);
br();
label("4. Biblioteca", false);
br();
label("5. Coordena��o de Curso", false);
//br();
//label("6. N�cleo de Extens�o e Pesquisa", false);
br();
label("7. TI", false);
br();
label("8. Patrim�nio", false);
br();
label("9. Procuradora Institucional", false);
br();
br();
label("Nome", false);
br();
text("txt_nome", 48, 94, "u", false, "", "", "");
br();
br();
label("E-mail", false);
br();
text("txt_email", 48, 94, "l", false, "", "", "");
br();
br();
label("Assunto", false);
br();
text("txt_assunto", 48, 94, "u", false, "", "", "");
br();
br();
label("Mensagem", false);
br();
text_area("txta_mensagem", 16, 72, false, "", "");
br();
br();
img("lib/captcha.php?l=150&a=50&tf=20&ql=5", "");
br();
label("Digite os caracteres da imagem", false);
br();
text("txt_captcha", 5, 20, "", false, "", "", "");
br();
br();
but_submit("but_enviar", "Enviar");
but_reset("but_limpar", "Limpar");

p_end();
page_end();
*/
?>
```

***SQL***

```
CREATE TABLE grupos_estudo_inscricoes (
  codigo int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  celular varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  matricula varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  primary key (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE grupos_estudo (
  codigo_grupos int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome_grupo varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  cod_grupos_estudo_insc int(11) NOT NULL,
    primary key (codigo_grupos),
    FOREIGN KEY(cod_grupos_estudo_insc) REFERENCES grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE grupos_estudo_sistema (
  codigo_sistema int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  periodo_letivo varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  situacao varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  cod_grupos_sistema int(11) not null,
  primary key (codigo_sistema),
  FOREIGN KEY(cod_grupos_sistema) REFERENCES grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)

);
```

ARQUIVO QUE RECEBE OS DADOS DO FORM E INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO

```
<?php

session_start();

include "bd.php";
//include "lib/util.php";
//include "../lib/phpmailer/phpmailer.php";

if ($_POST["but_enviar"] != "")
{
 $gravar = true;

 if ($_POST["nome"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Nome inv�lido(a) !");
  history_back();
 }

 if ($_POST["email"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("E-mail inv�lido(a) !");
  history_back();
 }

 
 if ($_POST["nome_grupo"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Escolha de grupo obrigatória!");
  history_back();
 }


 if ($_POST["celular"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Telefone inválido!");
  history_back();
 }

 if ($_POST["matricula"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Matrícula inválida!");
  history_back();
 }

 if ($_POST["situacao"] == "")
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Situação deve ser escolhida!");
  history_back();
 }
 
 /*
 if (($_POST["txt_captcha"] == "") || ($_POST["txt_captcha"] != $_SESSION["u_captcha"]))
 {
  $gravar = false;
  window_alert("Caracteres inv�lidos !");
  history_back();
 }
 
 if ($gravar == true)
 {
  $dr = dt_date();
  $hr = dt_time();
*/
  
   // Dados do formulário
  $grupos = $_POST['nome_grupo'];
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $celular = $_POST['celular'];
  $periodo_letivo = $_POST['periodo_letivo'];
  $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
  $situacao = $_POST['situacao'];



  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_inscricoes(nome,  email,  celular,    matricula) VALUES($nome', '$email', '$celular', '$matricula')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo_inscricoes = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo(nome_grupo, cod_grupos_estudo_insc) VALUES('$grupos','$grupos_estudo_inscricoes')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_sistema( periodo_letivo,  situacao, cod_grupos_sistema) VALUES('$periodo_letivo', '$situacao', '$grupos_estudo' )";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);

/*
if(!$con){
  echo "não conectou com o banco<br>";
} else{
  echo "conexão feita e ";
}

if($query){
  echo "gravou ";
}else{
  echo "não gravou";
}
*/

  }
 

?>
```

Bom, se tiver confuso, mando imagem. Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você está inserindo `cod_grupos_sistema` com o valor de  `$grupos_estudo`, sendo que sua relação está entre `FOREIGN KEY(cod_grupos_sistema) REFERENCES grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)`

---

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_inscricoes(nome,  email,  celular,    matricula) 
  VALUES($nome', '$email', '$celular', '$matricula')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo_inscricoes = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  // FOREIGN KEY(cod_grupos_estudo_insc) REFERENCES grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo(nome_grupo, cod_grupos_estudo_insc) 
  VALUES('$grupos','$grupos_estudo_inscricoes')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  // FOREIGN KEY(cod_grupos_sistema) REFERENCES grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_sistema( periodo_letivo,  situacao, cod_grupos_sistema) 
  VALUES('$periodo_letivo', '$situacao', '$grupos_estudo' )";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

O `cod_grupos_estudo_insc` e o `cod_grupos_sistema` se referem ao `grupos_estudo_inscricoes(codigo)`. Porém, no seu segundo `INSERT`, você está usando o `$grupos_estudo` ao invés do `$grupos_estudo_inscricoes`.

Enfim, para solucionar, parece que deve usar:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_inscricoes(nome,  email,  celular,    matricula) VALUES($nome', '$email', '$celular', '$matricula')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo_inscricoes = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo(nome_grupo, cod_grupos_estudo_insc) VALUES('$grupos','$grupos_estudo_inscricoes')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $grupos_estudo = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  $query = "INSERT INTO grupos_estudo_sistema( periodo_letivo,  situacao, cod_grupos_sistema) VALUES('$periodo_letivo', '$situacao', '$grupos_estudo_inscricoes' )";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: PS: Recomendo que utilize TRANSACTION, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html. Assim se uma inserção falhar, todas elas são desfeitas.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Vou tentar aqui novamente. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Tentei aqui e não gravou os dados no banco. Acho que já tinha feito dessa forma que falou e mudei pra essa que postei aqui. Porque como eu postei aqui, eu estou pegando o id errado, não é isso?

Comment: Pelo que vi do código, esse era o problema. Você pode usar o https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, para saber o erro exato.

Comment: Vou ver aqui. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: A conexão dá certo. Só não grava os dados no banco.

Comment: O `mysqli_error` retorna o último erro, coloque um `printf("%s \n", mysqli_query($con))`, assim verá a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Amigo, encontrei esse erro: Errormessage: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`grupos_estudos`.`grupos_estudo_sistema`, CONSTRAINT `grupos_estudo_sistema_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_grupos_sistema`) REFERENCES `grupos_estudo_inscricoes` (`codigo`))